# Vim automatically disable scan in included files for autocompletion when on networked filesystem

Tags: bash, vim

The following bash script checks whenever current `pwd` is mounted by `sshfs`:

```
if (! mountpoint -q $PWD ); then
  # not mounted
else
  # mounted
fi
```

I would like to Vim to do the same on current newly opened buffer and if the current directory is networked filesystem (means it is mounted) then Vim should execute `set complete-=i` command. Only in current split if possible.

Comment: `mountpoint` checks only if the dir is mountpoint, it won't tell you if it is a network filesystem. e.g., your `/home, /tmp, /boot....` all could be mountpoints

Comment: You are right. Just realized this some minutes ago. Is there a way to check that current directory is located on network filesystem?

Comment: Newermind `stat -f -L -c %T $PWD` do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the current buffer's directory is mounted:

```
:call system('mountpoint -q ' . shellescape(expand('%:h')))
:let isMountpoint = (v:shell_error == 0)
```

To hook this into buffer reads, invoke this through `:autocmd BufRead * ...`

The `'complete'` option is indeed buffer-local, so with `:setlocal complete-=i`, you can achieve that, too.

Now, you just need to combine the pieces:

```
:autocmd BufRead * call system('mountpoint -q ' . shellescape(expand('%:h'))) | if v:shell_error == 0 | setlocal complete-=i | endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it is working! Only problem I have is that `mountpoint -q $PWD` does not work in subfolders of networked filesystem.